# Mocked class not called within Mono.map()

Tags: junit, spring-webflux, project-reactor, spock

I have a Spring Webflux controller that delegates business logic and mapping to a couple `@Service` classes:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/v1/transactions")
class TransactionController {

    @Autowired
    TransactionService service

    @Autowired
    TransactionMapper mapper

    Flux<Transaction> getTransactions(@PathVariable String id) {
        service.getTransactions(id)
               .map({ mapper.mapTransaction(it) })
    
    }
}
```

My unit test works until it needs to get inside of the `map()` function.  I am receiving Too few invocations for 1 * mockMapper.mapTransaction(_) >> Flux.just(new MappedTransaction()).

```java
class TransactionControllerSpec extends Specification {
    def mockService = Mock(TransactionService)
    def mockMapper = Mock(TransactionMapper)

    def controller = new TransactionController(service: mockService, mapper: mockMapper)

    def "should call the transactions service to fetch a list of transactions"() {
        given: "an id"
        def id = "123"

        when: "the controller is called to fetch data"
        def result = controller.getTransactions(id)

        and: "code is executed"
        StepVerifier
            .create(result)
            .consumeNextWith({
               // some assertions here
            })

        then: "the service layer is called"
        1 * mockService.getTransactions(id) >> Flux.just(new Transaction())
        1 * mockMapper.mapTransaction(_) >> Flux.just(new MappedTransaction())
        //  Returns "Too few invocations (0 invocations)"
    }
}
```

I noticed that my breakpoint is not hit if I set it inside of the `Mono.map()` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, this was a huge oversight on my part.  But, the missing piece was that I forgot to tell `StepVerifier` to verify that the `Flux` was complete:

```java
        and: "code is executed"
        StepVerifier
            .create(result)
            .consumeNextWith({
               // some assertions here
            })
            .verifyComplete()
            //  subscribes to the Mono/Flux
```

Comment: Did it really solve the problem with "too few invocations"? O_o

Comment: @Mr.Ustiik It did -- Something I learned in another post is that `StepVerifier` belongs in the `when` block since it is executing code, or consuming a cold stream.  The `then` block allows you to then perform interaction-based assertions with spock.